# Remove two option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<button>remove other than 1 and 3</button>

<br />
<select id="sel">
        <option data-test="1">a</option>
        <option data-test="1">b</option>
        <option data-test="2">c</option>
        <option data-test="2">d</option>
        <option data-test="3">e</option>
        <option data-test="3">f</option>
        <option data-test="3">g</option>
        <option data-test="4">h</option>
        <option data-test="5">i</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('select option:not([data-test=1])').remove();
})
```

I would like remove all elements with a value in `data-test` other than 1 and 3. This code only keeps the elements with value `1`. What do I have to add for :not with jQuery to remove all option other than 1 and 3?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2xf/)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 $('select option:not([data-test=1],[data-test=3])').remove();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGsrb/)

See [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('select option:not([data-test=1],[data-test=3])').remove();
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2xf/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('select option').not('[data-test=1], [data-test=3]').remove();
});
```

**<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2xf/4/)</kbd>**

**Edit**: Check out *Vishal Suthar* and *A. V*'s answer for another very similar way.